# GitLab CI vs. Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci, drone.io

What is the difference between Jenkins and other CI like GitLab CI, drone.io coming with the Git distribution. On some research I could only come up that GitLab community edition doesn't allow Jenkins to be added, but GitLab enterprise edition does. Are there any other significant differences?

Comment: GitLab has also now put together a comparison of GitLab CI vs Jenkins: https://about.gitlab.com/comparison/gitlab-vs-jenkins.html

Comment: New link is : https://about.gitlab.com/comparison/pdfs/gitlab-vs-jenkins.pdf

Answer (score 134, accepted):

This is my experience:

At my work we manage our repositories with GitLab EE and we have a Jenkins server (1.6) running.

In the basis they do pretty much the same. They will run some scripts on a server/Docker image.

**TL;DR;**

- Jenkins is easier to use/learn, but it has the risk to become a plugin hell
- Jenkins has a GUI (this can be preferred if it has to be accessible/maintainable by other people)
- Integration with GitLab is less than with GitLab CI
- Jenkins can be split off your repository

Most CI servers are pretty straight forward ([concourse.ci](https://concourse-ci.org/), [gitlab-ci](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/), [circle-ci](https://circleci.com/), [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/), [drone.io](https://drone.io/), [gocd](https://www.gocd.org/) and what else have you). They allow you to execute shell/bat scripts from a YAML file definition. Jenkins is much more pluggable, and comes with a UI. This can be either an advantage or disadvantage, depending on your needs.

Jenkins is very configurable because of all the plugins that are available. The downside of this is that your CI server can become a spaghetti of plugins.

In my opinion chaining and orchestrating of jobs in Jenkins is much simpler (because of the UI) than via YAML (calling curl commands). Besides that Jenkins supports plugins that will install certain binaries when they are not available on your server (don't know about that for the others).

Nowadays ([Jenkins 2](http://jenkins-ci.org/2.0) also supports more "proper ci" with the `Jenkinsfile` and the [pipline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) plugin which comes default as from Jenkins 2), but used to be less coupled to the repository than i.e. GitLab CI.

Using YAML files to define your build pipeline (and in the end running pure shell/bat) is cleaner.

The plug-ins available for Jenkins allow you to visualize all kinds of reporting, such as test results, coverage and other static analyzers. Of course, you can always write or use a tool to do this for you, but it is definitely a plus for Jenkins (especially for managers who tend to value these reports too much).

Lately I have been working more and more with GitLab CI. At GitLab they are doing a really great job making the whole experience fun. I understand that people use Jenkins, but when you have GitLab running and available it is really easy to get started with GitLab CI. There won't be anything that will integrate as seamlessly as GitLab CI, even though they put quite some effort in third-party integrations.

- Their documentation should get you started in no time.
- The threshold to get started is very low.
- Maintenance is easy (no plugins).
- Scaling runners is simple.
- CI fully part of your repository.
- Jenkins jobs/views can get messy.

Some perks at the time of writing:

- Only support for a single file in the community edition. Multiples files in the [enterprise edition](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20868).

Comment: Jenkins can now get a nicer GUI thanks to [Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/)

Comment: As from gitlab 9.3 multiproject pipeline support is added. This was for me one of the main reasons to stick to Jenkins. Currently I am doing a PoC to check if I can manage with gitlab, as they are clearly also focussing on this now and they are evolving much quicker. Besides that I really love the UI and how it evolved over time.

Comment: The best with the yaml files is, that you document your changes to the pipeline directly where it should be.. in the repository as part of the source code. So you can have branches with different yaml files for different release branches. Sure, yaml merging could be mess :) Imaging merging two piplelines in jenkins, it is a much harder job.

Comment: jenkins provide much more tools than gitlab ci. gitlab/jenkins Together integration is possible and is really transparent for the user if well setted up.merging two piplelines in jenkins is easy with Jenkinsfile in your repository ....you will need gitlab and gitlab source branch plugins

Comment: What is meant by "Only support for a single file in the community edition. Multiples files in the enterprise edition." ? Sorry I tried to read the enclosed issue but couldn't relate.

Answer (score 66):

I agree with most of Rik's notes, but my opinion about which is a simpler is **the opposite**: GitLab is proving to be an awesome tool to work with.

Most of the power comes from being **self-contained** and [integrating everything](https://about.gitlab.com/direction/#scope) in the same product under the same browser tab: from repository browser, issue board or build history to deployment tools and [monitoring](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/01/05/prometheus-and-gitlab/).

I'm using it right now to automate and test how an application installs on different Linux distributions, and it's just **blazing fast to configure** (try to open a complex Jenkins job configuration in Firefox and wait for the non-responsive script to come up vs. how lightweight is to edit `.gitlab-ci.yml`).

The time spent on configuring/scaling slaves is considerably less thanks to the [runner binaries](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install); plus the fact that in [GitLab.com](http://gitlab.com) you get quite decent and free shared runners.

Jenkins feels *more manual* after some weeks of being a power user of GitLab CI, e.g. duplicating jobs per branch, installing plugins to do simple stuff such as SCP upload. The only use-case I have faced where I miss it as for today is when more than one repository is involved; that needs to be nicely figured out yet.

BTW, I'm currently writing a series on GitLab CI to demonstrate how it's not that hard to configure your repository CI infrastructure with it. Published last week, the first piece is introducing the basics, pros and cons and differences with other tools: *[Fast and natural Continuous Integration with GitLab CI](https://solidgeargroup.com/gitlab_countinuous_integration_intro)*

Comment: I totally agree on you about Gitlab. At the time of writing gitlab was not as complete as it is nowadays. I like Gitlab as a tool very much, and really appreciate all the work the guys are putting into it.

Comment: @alfageme: I will check out your Reports on the mentioned site

Anyway: Thanks to all your explanations. At this very moment im going to decide if we use gitlabCI or Jenkins for our CI -Stuff.

Comment: @MaxS What did you end up using ?

Comment: @Rik I do like Gitlab CI however I hear arguments from the other side saying its hard to maintain yaml files because there is no reusability because lot of the yaml files in a pipeline follow the same structure and Templating is not seen as a superior option to jenkinsfile because jenkinsfile uses groovy. so it's all about code vs configuration for reusability. can you please share your thoughts on this?

Comment: @user1870400 I am not entirely sure what you mean with templating. Because as far as I can see it, it is just a file in your repository. And that is no different compared to your `Jenkinsfile`. You are right that in your `Jenkinsfile` you have groovy (+ additional java libs) available to run code, where the `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file will mainly support shell, but (depending on the location of the runner).
On the other hand you can call all this from a shell script as well, but the downside is that you are creating machine dependencies (which in my opinion are not very transparent).

Comment: I think that one of the plus sides of Jenkins is that you can run any SCM (and mixed, you are not bound to a single SCM) whereas Gitlab is for git repositories only. @user1870400 can you explain a bit more what you mean with the templating/reusability, because as far as I can see that is not really a problem (or advantage/disadvantage from one compared to another)

Comment: Hi @Rik I meant templating for yaml files not jenkinsfile. jenkinsfile is  groovy code whereas yaml files are all about (configuration). The problem here is that how can we resuse yaml config files? because lot of the jobs follow the same structure in a pipeline. Reusability in code is easy to do so jenkinsfile excels there except I'm not a big fan of groovy. I wish it was more python :) Inorder, to reuse yaml files people normally do templating so yaml files will have bunch of placeholders like this `{{ variable_name }}` such that linux sed can replace that place holder

Comment: @Alfageme - I started using Gitlab CI as well and moving away from Jenkins. I use it in moment for auto-build, upload to Nexus, deploy to DEV env and run unit tests. Such sequence is executed on project level(standard). After DEV I also need manage multi-project (Gitlab group) deployment. I created GUI which uses Gitlab, Nexus APIs, etc. where you select latest TAG of project to deploy and group-projects latest tags are deployed as well(naive). I work on extension to support version matrix definition(projec1v1.1 is compatible with project2v3.2), I will one feature request at gitlab for this.

Comment: No need for duplicating jobs per branch in Jenkins if you use [Multibranch Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/).

Comment: @kensai I'd love to see some screenshots of that GUI-tool and know more about your particular use-case :)

Comment: @JohnnyBaloney yeah, I've used the plugin in some past projects, and as I mentioned both in the answer and the article, It's not that Jenkins lacks GitLab CI features, but follows a complete different and modular approach, more powerful but heavy and difficult to setup.

Comment: @Alfageme - the case is straight. We don't have capabilities to build auto pipelines through all environments from dev to prod. There is required manual test step. To prevent dev team to waste time on deployments in TEST, QA and PROD envs. So this GUI is for Project managers/Test leaders, it is deployment driven by business, not by dev. The gui design is similar to Tower project by Indeed.com (i have been asked to work for them in Japan in the past) http://engineering.indeedblog.com/blog/

Comment: I have been using Gitlab-CI for building and running tests on the iOS app. Since I could not get a docker image with Xcode, I ended up using a local machine as runner. When comparing with Xcode bots, I think gitlab CI is also quite useful for the developers since some of the features like automated email notifications are easier with GitLab.

Comment: gitlab CI may be sufficient for small projects using only a single build configuration. I prefer to have some good tools that collaborate together than a single one that does not provide the full necessary tools. What is really the added value of gitlab CI ?????? why reinvent what exists ?

Comment: GitLab gives you a GUI to kick off jobs (you can make things require a manual button push if you want) and comes with example YML for pretty much any programming language or even an entire "auto devops" pipeline that is language agnostic. Ever since I've found GitLab CI, I've been tearing down TeamCity and Jenkins servers left and right.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml/blob/master/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: GitLab CI has an almost fatal flaw, ime.   If you're used to Jenkins pipelines, you naturally associate Jenkins Stages with GitLab Jobs.  So a typical Java pipeline has stages/jobs like Build, Unit-Test, Package, Publish.   Unfortunately, every GL Job runs in a brand new container instance and, by default, shares nothing with previous or following Jobs.    This is antithetical to good DevOps DRY practices.  Build the binaries exactly once, then test them, then package them, etc.   Even when sharing the Maven local repo across jobs as GL artifacts, you have to rebuild everything for every job.

Comment: The other not-so-great thing about GitLab is that building re-usable build jobs does not work well in practice.  Jenkins ability to use Groovy libraries is a much, much better approach in practice.    With GitLab it's always copy/paste.  If there are changes that affect multiple projects, then every project has to be maintained separately.   This is a substantial burden for larger development organizations.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel have you looked at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html for sharing artifacts across subsequent pipeline steps?

Comment: @CharlieReitzel also, I have used includes (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) and extends (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) in the past to avoid copy/paste and keep things DRY. You can check the manual SAST configuration for reference (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#configure-sast-manually)

Comment: @Alfageme  Neither `include` nor `extends` support parameters.  In practice, this makes it difficult to design re-usable build components for large teams.   Groovy libraries support parameters because they're just groovy classes.  It is a much simpler and more robust extension mechanism.

Comment: @Alfageme If you read the best practices for using GitLab `cache:` , which look reasonable to me, you need to tag the runners for compatibility.  The implication is that GitLab administrators have to define the cache and apply tags appropriately to the runners.   This doesn't really work in a large organization with dozens of teams.  At least with artifacts, each team can control their own builds.   It just slows down the build and costs the company more in CPU and storage ($$).  That's probably cheaper than having an already overburdened DevOps team support every team's cache needs.

Answer (score 27):

First of all, as of today, GitLab Community Edition can be fully interoperable with Jenkins. No question.

In what follows, I give some feedback on a successful experience combining both Jenkins and GitLab CI. I shall also discuss whether you should use both or only one of them, and for what reason.

I hope this will give you quality information on your own projects.

#### GitLab CI and Jenkins strengths

**GitLab CI**

GitLab CI is naturally integrated in GitLab SCM. You can create pipelines using `gitlab-ci.yml` files and manipulate them through a graphical interface.

These pipelines as code can obviously be stored in the code base, enforcing the "everything as code" practice (access, versioning, reproducibility, reusability, etc.).

GitLab CI is a great visual management tool:

- all members of the teams (including the non-technical ones) have quick and easy access to applications life cycle status.
- therefore it can be used as a *interactive* and *operational* dashboard for release management.

**Jenkins**

Jenkins is a great build tool. It's strength is in its many plugins. Especially, I've had great luck in using interface plugins between Jenkins and other CI or CD tools. This is always a better option than to redevelop (possibly badly) a dialog interface between two components.

Pipeline as code is also available using `groovy`scripts.

#### Using GitLab CI and Jenkins together

It might sound a bit redundant at first, but combining GitLab CI and Jenkins is quite powerful.

- GitLab CI orchestrates (chains, runs, monitors...) pipelines and one can benefit its graphical interface integrated to GitLab
- Jenkins runs the job and facilitates dialog with third-party tools.

Another benefit of this design is to have loose coupling between the tools:

- we could replace any of the build factory components without having to rework the entire CI/CD process
- we could have a heterogeneous build environment, combining (possibly several) Jenkins, TeamCity, you name it, and still have a single monitoring tool.

#### The Trade-off

Well, of course, there is a price to pay for this design: the initial set-up is cumbersome and you need to have a minimal level of understanding of many tools.

For this reason, I don't recommend such a set-up unless

- you have many third-party tools to deal with. That's when Jenkins comes in super handy with its many plugins.
- you have to deal with complex applications with heterogeneous technologies, having each a different build environment, and still need to have a unified application life cycle management UI.

If you are in neither of these situations, you're probably better off with only one of the two, but not both.

#### If I had to pick one

Both GitLab CI and Jenkins have pros and cons. Both are powerful tools. So which one to choose?

**Answer 1**

Choose the one that your team (or someone close) has already a certain level of
expertise in.

**Answer 2**

If you're all complete freshman in CI technologies, just pick one and get going.

- If you're using GitLab and have a knack for everything as code, it makes total sens to choose GitLab CI.
- If you have to dialog with many other CI/CD tools or absolutely need that GUI to build your jobs, go for Jenkins.

Those of you that are using GitLab and are not sure they will keep doing so still have to keep in mind that, having chosen GitLab CI would imply to trash all your CI / CD pipelines.

Final word is: the balance leans a *little* bit towards Jenkins because of its many plugins, but chances are GitLab CI will quickly fill the gap.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: THX!

Answer (score 9):

I would like to add some findings from my recent experimenting with GitLab CI. Features that came with 11.6 and 11.7 are just awesome!

Specifically I love `only` conditions which basically allow you to build separate pipelines for `merge_request` or `push` (the complete list is [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-complex))

Also, I really like the absence of plugins. When I need some more complex functionality I just write a custom Docker image that handles required functionality (it's the same concept as you can see in [drone.io](https://docs.drone.io/plugins/examples/bash/)).

If you are wondering about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), it's absolutely possible nowadays! You can write your "templates,"

```
.myTemplate:
  image: node:10.14.2
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run test
```

Put them to some public repository, include them in the main pipeline:

```
include:
  - remote: https://....
```

And use them to extend some job:

```
test:
  extends: .myTemplate
  only:
    refs: ["master"]
    variables:
      - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

**I love GitLab CI so much!** Yeah, it (so far) can't draw nice graphs with coverage and so on, but overall it's a really neat tool!

**Edit (2019-02-23):** [here's my post about](https://www.ackee.cz/blog/en/experimenting-with-gitlab-ci/) things I love in GitLab CI. It was written in 11.7 "era" so when you're reading this answer, GitLab CI probably has many more features.

**Edit (2019-07-10):** Gitlab CI now supports multiple `extends` e.g.

```
extends:
 - .pieceA
 - .pieceB
```

Check the official documentation to get more info about [multiple extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends)

Answer (score 1):

if your build/publish/deploy and test jobs are not heavily complex then using gitlab ci has natural advantages.

Since gitlab-ci.yml is present alongside your code in every branch, you can modify your ci/cd steps particularly tests(which differs across environments) more effectively.

For an example, you want to do unit testing for any checkin to dev branch whereas you might want carry out full fledged functional testing on QA branch and a limited only get type of tests on production this can be achieved easily using gitlab ci.

second advantage apart from great UI is its ability to use docker images for executing any stage keeps the host runner intact and thus less error prone.

moreover gitlab ci would automatically checkin for you and you dont have to manage jenkins master separately